# In the news this month, September 2015

Tags: knowledge, anagram

I have an IDEA for a puzzle.
I think I'll add two letters.
But am I a puzzle about a recent discovery?
Or a very old conquest, newly recoined?
The news would tell you both of these are very new and very old.

Which two things am I talking about? And what's their connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two words are

> Naledi, the new hominid species

and

> Denali, the recently renamed mountain

Both

> differ by two letters from IDEA. Also, both stories involve climbing mountains.

Comment: Specifically, they're anagrams - which is the hidden tag. Good job!